# episode from OLD B&W TV horror show from late 1950s or early 60s

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have been trying to recall what the name of a program was that showed this one episode that I saw when I was maybe three years old.

What I recall is two men (hoodlums, maybe bank robbers, I guess) who came into town at night on motorcycles.  They wound up staying in an empty house, as no one would open the door to let them into their homes.
During the night, one awakens from hearing a noise from the upper floor of the house, and goes to investigate.  His friend wakes up to find him gone, and as he was searching for him, saw this ghastly looking female coming down the staircase, carrying the friends' head in one hand and an ax or hatchet in the other. She reminded me of the Statue of Liberty, except for the look of complete...nothing on her face. Long white dress, long unkempt hair, and that face.

I have wanted to see this ever since I can remember, but I can't recall what it was.  Perhaps the old Chillers show, or Thriller....or something along that line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly *Pigeons from Hell* as per [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132194/terrifying-story-about-2-friends-who-spend-a-night-in-a-deserted-mansion-where/132198#132198).

> The story opens as two New Englanders, John Branner and his brother Griswell, are travelling in the South and spend the night in a deserted plantation manor. Griswell awakens from a troubled sleep to see Branner walking up the stairs in a trance. He is horrified when Branner returns, no longer alive but an animated corpse gripping the bloody axe that had split his skull. Griswell flees the house in a blind panic and runs aimlessly into the woods.

If so it was indeed shown on Boris Karloff's *Thriller*:

Points for it are the two men stopping at a deserted house and the dead friend killed with an axe, as well as being on Boris Karloff's *Thriller*. Minus points, there's no female figure carrying the head, but rather it's the reanimated body.

Comment: I watched this, and this isn't it.  Being as I was only 3 when I watched it, the point that scared me the most, and that which I recall the most, is that woman, walking down the stairs with the head and ax.  It reminded me of the Statue of Liberty, except for the look of complete...nothing on her face.  Long white dress, long unkempt hair, and that face.  But thank you for trying to help.  Still looking, though.

Comment: I added the new details to the question.